# Solr 1.4 to 3.3 - Field collapsing

Tags: solr, solrj

I have the following code (Solr 1.4)

```
FieldCollapseResponse fieldCollapseResponse = resp.
            getFieldCollapseResponse();
```

I am looking for the code doing the same thing but for Solr 3.3.

Thanks for help
Medley

Answer (score 0):

["Field collapsing" has been replaced with "result grouping"](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing), which subsumes the former. But they have very different response structures, and [SolrJ hasn't yet addressed this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2637).

Comment: It means that I have to wait for Solr 3.4 or 4.0.

Comment: @Medley: no, it means you should apply the patch attached to the JIRA issue and test it and contribute to the community effort of getting this feature right.

Comment: Ok I will do it. I have to test a index whose size is 20 GB.

Comment: @Medley: great! be sure to post back any feedback or bugs to the JIRA issue!